# How do i close the Chrome browser session using Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've already tried using

```
driver.quit
```

or

```
driver.close
```

But both of them haven't helped much even after the Selenium script ends, the browser session remains open.

I am Using Chrome Driver, any help would be appreciated.

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 180
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome,:http_client => client, :switches => [--ignore-certificate-errors]
```